# Why does an error occur when saving the form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

There are two models

**models1**

```
class Work(models.Model):

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_projects')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_work')
    ...
    responsibility = models.TextField("employee work responsibility", blank=True)
```

**models2**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("project name", max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField("project description")
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(
        Technology, verbose_name="technologies used on the project")
```

I use modeinlineformset to create new objects

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'technologies']


ProjectFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, Work,
                                       fields=['responsibility', 'start_year', 'start_month', 'end_year', 'end_month'],
                                       extra=1)
```

**and my views.py**

```
class WorkCreateView(AuthorizedMixin, CreateView):
    """
    Create new course instances
    """
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'work_edit.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        ....

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        project_form = ProjectFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and project_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, project_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, project_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, project_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        project_form.instance = self.object
        project_form.save(commit=False)
        project_form.instance.employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        project_form.save()
        return redirect('{}#experience'.format(reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})))

    def form_invalid(self, form, project_form):
        ...
```

But get an error

```
null value in column "employee_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I know what this mistake means, but I don't  understand why this happens if I assign a value of the current `employee` to `instance.employee`.

**UPD**

I tried to change views

```
def form_valid(self, form, project_form):
    self.object = form.save()
    instances = project_form.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
        instance.employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        instance.save()
    return redirect('{}#experience'.format(reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})))
```

But got new error

```
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'project'.
```

Comment: remember `project_form` is an inlinemodel_formset, not a form. The `instance` is the `Project` instance, not the object being saved. You need loop through all the objects being saved: `works = project_form.save(commit=False); for work in works: work.employee = ...`

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset)'s the documentation about saving modelformsets.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried to change views (question updated) but got error `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'project'.`

Comment: You still have to set the instance of the formset (between self.object = form.save() and instances = ...)

Comment: After I put in  `project_form.instance = self.object` after `self.object = form.save()`  it worked out. Thank you!